# ViewPager margin in PageTransformer transformations

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager in which each of it's views is a representation of card on a deck. Each card has a shadow on the border using the ViewPager margin:

```
cardsViewPager.setPageMargin(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / 20);
cardsViewPager.setPageMarginDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
```

And it works as expected.

But, if I add a PageTransformer so that the cards on the right will stack on top of the cards on the left:

```
public class ScalePageTransformer implements PageTransformer {  
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;

    public ScalePageTransformer(ViewPager viewPager) {
        this.mViewPager = viewPager;
    }

    @Override
    public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
        if (position <= 0) {
            int pageWidth = mViewPager.getWidth();
            final float translateValue = position * -pageWidth;
            if (translateValue > -pageWidth) {
                page.setTranslationX(translateValue);
            } else {
                page.setTranslationX(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I do this by:

```
cardsViewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new ScalePageTransformer(cardsViewPager));
```

But now, the margin does not appear. If I had a zoom out effect on the PageTransformer, I can see when the current card is being scaled down, that the margin drawable is below the current card on the screen. Here is a pic to describe what's happening:

[image]

The blue card is being swiped from the right to left on top of the red card. Since the red card has a scale transformation, we can see the margin drawable in black behind it.

Is there a way to force the margin drawable to be on top of the red card? Shouldn't this be the default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
cardsViewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ScalePageTransformer(cardsViewPager));
```

First argument is the drawing order

Answer (score -3):

Try using this code for the transformation stage of your View Pages :

```
private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.85f;
private static final float MIN_ALPHA = 0.5f;

public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
    int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
    int pageHeight = view.getHeight();

    if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
        // This page is way off-screen to the left.
        view.setAlpha(0);

    } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
        // Modify the default slide transition to shrink the page as well
        float scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_SCALE, 1 - Math.abs(position));
        float vertMargin = pageHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
        float horzMargin = pageWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
        if (position < 0) {
            view.setTranslationX(horzMargin - vertMargin / 2);
        } else {
            view.setTranslationX(-horzMargin + vertMargin / 2);
        }

        // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
        view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
        view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

        // Fade the page relative to its size.
        view.setAlpha(MIN_ALPHA +
                (scaleFactor - MIN_SCALE) /
                (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - MIN_ALPHA));

    } else { // (1,+Infinity]
        // This page is way off-screen to the right.
        view.setAlpha(0);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: copy paste from android developer website won't help anybody. try to understand  the problem then post a comment.