# Use viewpager as carousel (after the app start issue)

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager, carousel

Currently i am using `ViewPager` to do a carousel effect menu
However i am facing some initialization issue

This is how i want my carousel to look like **after the app start**, look at the 2nd tile which is the video tile, it is dimmer and smaller than the 1st tile which is the music tile

[image]

However what i get is like this **after the app start** (if i didnt move it or drag it)

[image]

To make the carousel to look like the first image, i need to manually move it or drag it first, then everything look what it should be

Below is my code snippet for setting up the viewpage

```
    pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pager.setPageMargin(-700);//so that it look like carousel
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(Menu.size());
    pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageAdapter);
    pager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
```

Below is my code snippet for including the zoomoutpagetransformer for animation between pages

```
public class ZoomOutPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
    private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.85f;
    private static final float MIN_ALPHA = 0.5f;

public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
    int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
    int pageHeight = view.getHeight();

    if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
        // This page is way off-screen to the left.
        view.setAlpha(0);

    } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
        // Modify the default slide transition to shrink the page as well
        float scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_SCALE, 1 - Math.abs(position));
        float vertMargin = pageHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
        float horzMargin = pageWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
        if (position < 0) {
            view.setTranslationX(horzMargin - vertMargin / 2);// positive
        } else {
            view.setTranslationX(-horzMargin + vertMargin / 2);// negative
        }

        // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
        view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
        view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

        // Fade the page relative to its size.
        view.setAlpha(MIN_ALPHA + (scaleFactor - MIN_SCALE) / (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - MIN_ALPHA));

        textview.setText(String.valueOf(scaleFactor) + "\n" + String.valueOf(vertMargin) + "\n"
                + String.valueOf(horzMargin));

    } else { // (1,+Infinity]
        // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            view.setAlpha(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone has any idea how to let it look like what it should be after the app start without i move or drag it first?

Comment: Did you try pager.setCurrentItem(firstItem); ?

Comment: Just tried, doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the PageTransformer's transformPage() method return the wrong position when you play with padding and margin on the view pager. Seems to be a framework bug as stated [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64046).

Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28169806/795245) in this related question providing a workaround.