# How to implement Facebook App like image Zoom-In/ Zoom-Out?

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-animation

I have tried a lot to implement this type of effect. [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w9fntuils78yqp2/image-gallery.mp4?dl=0)

I have successfully implemented the view-pager in list-view. but now i want to apply zoom-in zoom-out effect on image click like Facebook app.

Is there any library or technique to implement such effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be amazed to see the default android documentation provides complete guideline with samples to do that, Click [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html) or [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html)

Comment: Thank you. It works fine with imageview. i'll try to implement it with viewpager.

Comment: Accept the answer if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code.

```
ViewPager imageGalleryPager = (ViewPager) productImageView.findViewById((R.id.pager));
imageGalleryPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());


public class ZoomOutPageTransformer implements PageTransformer {
private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.85f;

private static final float MIN_ALPHA = 0.5f;

@Override
public void transformPage(View view,
        float position) {
    int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
    int pageHeight = view.getHeight();

    if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
        // This page is way off-screen to the left.
        view.setAlpha(0);

    } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
        // Modify the default slide transition to shrink the page as well
        float scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_SCALE, 1 - Math.abs(position));
        float vertMargin = pageHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
        float horzMargin = pageWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
        if (position < 0) {
            view.setTranslationX(horzMargin - vertMargin / 2);
        } else {
            view.setTranslationX(-horzMargin + vertMargin / 2);
        }

        // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
        view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
        view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

        // Fade the page relative to its size.
        view.setAlpha(MIN_ALPHA + (scaleFactor - MIN_SCALE) / (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - MIN_ALPHA));

    } else { // (1,+Infinity]
        // This page is way off-screen to the right.
        view.setAlpha(0);
    }
}
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159243/viewpager-margin-in-pagetransformer-transformations)

Comment: Thank you for answering but this is not the effect i wanted. What i want is "On Image click, It should get expanded from center-crop to fill parent with Zoom out animation."